# Securing Restful API

Tags: android, web-services, restful-authentication

I am creating a Restful Web service, which shall then be accessed by a website and native android applications. I am new to Restful and want to understand what shall be the best security mechanism I can use to secure this website.

I have read about:

1. OAuth 1/2
2. Http sessions (which are not suggested)
3. Http Header mechanisms

What are the advantages/disadvantages of them vis-a-vis the other?

Comment: You also could consider an API_KEY, passed in the URI or the request.

Comment: The best security depends on [what type of service you have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870779/do-we-need-a-security-signature-for-the-web-service-response/20912293#20912293) and what you consider to be the appropriate level of security given your needs and requirements.